# Book about a boy with telepathic powers who escapes a lab and goes to a shop to change his clothes, adopting a goth/alt. look

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, psychic

It's been since middle school that I read this book but I do not remember the title, cover, or author.

In the book, a boy with telepathic powers escapes a lab, goes to change his look at a shop- which suddenly interests the store clerk girl with his new goth/alt. look. There are a few other characters, like a boy who was abused by his father, a kid who could find lost items, and a few others. It skips P.O.V. constantly between the kids.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].